# Measuring fork steerer diameter

Tags: fork, headset

I've acquired a Raleigh Suntour (circa 1990s) frame which I am re-fitting. I need to refit the headset and so I need to know the dimensions of the steerer column. The frame had a threaded stem.

I've measured the external diameter as about 22-23mm (so about 85-86% of an inch). I measured it by applying measuring calipers to the outside of the steerer column i.e not the cups for the ball bearings.

I've looked at various websites (such as Parktool) about standard threaded headset sizes and they say they range from one inch to one and a quarter. So even the smallest standard is quite a bit larger than my measurement.

I've checked my measurement several times and I'm sure it is about right. Do I have a steerer with an obsolete measurement or have I made some silly mistake.

Thanks in advance

Chris

Comment: Are you measuring the fork steerer  ( the part with external threads) or the quill stem ( the piece the handle bars attach to)??

Comment: Hi Mikes. I'm measuring the fork steerer.

Comment: Do you really get different values for each measurement? If not, could you give the accurate measurement?

Comment: 90s and threadded?  theres a 99% chance its a standard 1" steerer tube.

Comment: By the way, for threaded stems the vertical part the one to be measured. Horizontal part doesn't really matter. Threadless stems don't have the vertical part and the steerer column extends outside the frame, this might be the source of confusion.

Comment: I asked about where you are measuring because a standard 1 inch steerer  uses a 22.2mm stem which is roughly 7/8th of an inch. Very close to your measurements.

Comment: @Chris You should move your comment to an answer and mark it as answered. This clears it from the unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was measuring in the right place (steerer) but I was using my new vermier caliper incorrectly. I've tried again and the steerer is about one inch. Apologies and thank you for all your help